# Going from Listactivity to Listfragment

Tags: android, listview, android-asynctask, android-fragments

For the last couple of days i have been trying to go from current listactivity to listfragment. I load the data into my Listactivity through a an ArrayAdapter which works great. The data is first collected from a remote server then inserted into an SQLite database. When the data is presented i load the data into an custom BaseAdapter. All of this works great. I would really like to update my UI by using listfragments. This especially because I have many clients who use a tablet.

I know how to create larger views for tablets, but would like my apps to be presented like in an iPad. To my understand it is possible to do this with fragments. So far i have managed to get the listfragments working with static data. The problem is I don't know how to load the data that is present in the array adapter into the listfragment.

I use Async tasks to retrieve , store and present the data in a listview.

Could anyone help me with loading data from an async task into a listfragment? Currently I load everything into a listview in a listactivity.

Thanks

Comment: I've read the following : http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/multi-pane-layouts.html. But can't manage to change what I have to something like this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially it has to be the same. Just the container is different(Activity to Fragment), the internal implementation should ideally remain the same. So i would say create AsyncTask use the same components, inside onPostExecute() method, you can do a setListAdapter(adapter), something like below:

```
class MyFragment extentsListFragment{

//define constructors if any 
public void onResume(){

    LoadData loadData = new LoadData();
    loadData.execute();

}
//unimplementedMethods





private class LoadData extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    private Object object = null;

    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

        //make a call to the server and save the data in SQLite DB
        // Make a call to the database to get your data
        object = getObjectFromDB();

        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        if(object == null || object.length <= 0) {
            setListAdapter(null);
            return;
        }




        // assuming object has your data, say it's an Array  List, work on it and setListAdapter
        adapter = ...
        setListAdapter(adapter)
    }

    private Object getObjectFromDB() {
        // do whatever
        return object;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Thanks stack_ved, I will implement this and get back to you.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a step by step guide for a basic scenario:

1)Create a new fragment.java file, with a super plain implementation of a fragment.

```
package com.a;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ListFragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class MenuFragment extends ListFragment 
{

public static final String TAG = "MenuFragment";

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list, null);
    return v;
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    //
    // insert code here to setup and call setListAdapter()
    //
}

@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView lv, View v, int position, long id) 
{

}
}
```

2)Look for your setContentView in your listactivity code, use that layout as a parameter to  the inflate() call under onCreateView()

```
setContentView(R.layout.main);
```

to

```
View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main, null);
```

3)Move the rest of your code under your listactivity onCreate() to listfragmentt OnCreateView(). You probably have some code setting up the controls such as the below:

```
text = (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.text);
```

It will become this:

```
text = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.text);
```

Note that v is the view, returned from the inflate call.

4)If your code has references to "this", you will get an error. Replace that with "getActivity()".

5)Check what code you have left, and find the right place to put them in the new file. Hopefully the above covers the basics.