# Android: migrate from ListActivity to ListFragment

Tags: android, listview, adapter, listactivity, android-listfragment

the question has already been asked by someone but I couldn't find any complete answer.
I've written a ListActivity (a list of monuments) with an ArrayAdapter. Bitmaps are loaded in background, saved in cache, in DB, in disk and then returned. The user can change the elements in the adapter with a click, so the method setListAdapter is called several times.

In the ListActivity the only thing is done, right now, is ask the server (or the DB) for a list of places, and call setListAdapter on an adapter with that places.

In the method getView of the adapter, the only thing I have is calling a method "loadBitmap(..)" that does everything in background, and populate the ImageViews of the listView with the bitmaps.

Everything's working fine, but: I want to use a ListFragment instead of a ListActivity for many reasons (first is that this list will be placed in a ViewPager, as a tab).

What do I have to do? Can I use the same adapter or I have to change something in there?

Thank you very much,

Lorenzo

Comment: Check out the response in this conversation:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14031093/going-from-listactivity-to-listfragment/20967288#20967288

Comment: Check out the response here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14031093/going-from-listactivity-to-listfragment/20967288#20967288

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ListFragment` is very similar to `ListActivity`. It provides the same API like `setListAdapter` etc You will be able to use the same adapter with it. 
In case you need a Context or the enclosing Activity you can call `ListAdapter.getActivity`

Comment: So all I have to do is just enclose a ListFragment within an Activity, and move all the code in the fragment?

Comment: Yes, that should be it.

Comment: I tried this and I am getting one error which I can't solve in this line of code: `setContentView(getResourcesId(context, "activity_rn_inbox", "layout"));`
The error is: "The method setContentView(int) is undefined for the type RichNotifInboxActivity"

Comment: @Soph Make sure your RichWhateverActivity extends Activity. Then it should be setContentView(R.layout.your_xml_layout)